# Can I put recaptcha on wordpress homepage?

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

Is there any way to put Google recaptcha on the homepage of a wordpress website, so guests can't browse the site unless they pass the recaptcha test?

So far, I was able to put recaptcha only in pages where user needs to enter data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To add CAPTCHA protection to a WordPress site using the Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA) plugin, follow these steps:

Log in to WordPress as the administrator.
Under Dashboard, click Plugins, and then click Add New.
In the Search text box, type google captcha.
Click Search Plugins.
Locate the Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA) plugin, and then click Install Now.
After WordPress finishes installing the plugin, under Dashboard, click Plugins, and then click Installed Plugins.
Locate the Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA) plugin, and then click Activate.
Click Settings.
You must create a public and private key to use Google Captcha. To do this, click the registration link under Authentication, and then follow the instructions.
After you receive your keys from Google, type the public key into the Public Key text box, and type the private key into the Private Key text box.
Under Options, select the settings that you want, and then click Save Changes.
CAPTCHAs are now activated for your site. To test this, go to your WordPress site's front page, and then click the comment link for a post. WordPress displays a CAPTCHA in the submission form.
More Information
For more information about the Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA) plugin, please visit http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-captcha.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to add recaptcha on front page without having any form to submit. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Hello,
You can use shortcode in your index head section to execute captcha first in your Homepage

Comment: I will try the plugin that you suggest and let you know

Comment: It has to be the pro version, so it's not a preferred solution. It will have to be free